# Reference for relative operation expense

Tags: optimization

Does anyone know a good reference to help with understanding the relative cost of operations like copying variables, declaring new variables, FileIO, array operations, etc? I've been told to study decompilation and machine code but a quick reference would be nice. For example, something to tell me how much worse

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    new double d = 7.65;
    calc(d);
}
```

is than

```
double d = 7.65;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    calc(d);
}
```

Comment: Okay so I made that pseudocode up, but shouldn't there be some general trends among different parsers? The one I care about the most is Java.

Comment: No. The answer will vary wildly amongst different language platforms.

Comment: Alright, I'll just delete this in a while then unless someone can salvage it with a good answer.

Comment: You could salvage it by editing the question to talk about Java!

Comment: Ha ha, gotta do some research first. I guess I'll just leave it. There's an answer!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf) is a nice paper by Felix von Leitner on the state of C compiler optimization. I learned of it on [this](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3674) Lambda the Ultimate page.

The performance of operations you mention such as file I/O, memory access, and computation are highly dependent on a computer's architecture. Much of the optimization of software for today's desktop computers is focused on cache memory.

You would gain much from an architecture book or course. [Here's](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece548/handouts/02key.pdf) a good example from CMU.